# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "pivot": syntax error

Tags: r, shiny, pivot, transpose, partition

i got an error in this part on before for row no i used partion function but it gave me error now i replace it with 
other query,i want to transpose row into column and also please any one give how to create dynamic item columns
[this is a look of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqkzz.png)

```
v<-sqldf(
   "select id,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10
    from(
           select a.*,'item' || count(*) row_no 
           from ddd a join ddd b on a.id = b.id and b.rowid <= a.rowid
           group by a.rowid
           order by a.rowid
    )Temp
    pivot
    (
        max(name)
        for row_no in (item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10)
    )Piv"
)
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, SQLite doesn't have a `pivot()` function. At first glance, your syntax looks Oracle-like; are you using Oracle or SQLite? If the former, why are you using `rsqlite_send_query`, and if the latter, where did you get the information that `pivot()` exists in SQLite?

Comment: i am using r studio in which i used sqlite as i am i am using sqldf in it

Comment: You didn't answer the second half of my question. I'm quite sure that SQLite doesn't support the `pivot()` function, so where did you get the information that `pivot()` exists in SQLite?

Comment: so what can i use to get same result i want to now that i want to result of changing row in to column